# Add shaded rectangle with select Box corners in Plotly R

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, plotly, htmlwidgets

I am trying to create an application where if a user employs the Box Select tool in Plotly, then a filled rectangle will appear alongside the Box Select. To accomplish this, I am trying to call Plotly.addTrace() to create a rectangle object (type: rect) that has the corners of the box the user selected.

I am able to obtain the coordinates of the corners of the box the user selected (in the code they are called xMin, xMax, yMin, and yMax). However, I then try to create a variable called drawRect that can be added to Plotly. This does nothing at this time, though.

I based some of the syntax off a post about Python Plotly (https://plot.ly/python/shapes/). However, I am working with Plotly in R. Is there any similar rectangle object that I could use in Plotly R?

Below is MWE showing my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point(alpha=0) + xlim(0,5) +ylim(-3,3)
  gp <- ggplotly(p)

  set.seed(3)
  myDF <- data.frame(X1=rnorm(10,-1), X2=rnorm(10,-1), X3=rnorm(10,-1), X4=rnorm(10,1), X5=rnorm(10,1), X6=rnorm(10,1))
  colNms <- colnames(myDF)
  nVar <- length(colNms)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    gp %>% onRender("
    function(el, x, data) {

    var myDF = data.myDF
    var Traces = [];
    var dLength = myDF.length
    var vLength = data.nVar
    var cNames = data.colNms
    for (a=0; a<dLength; a++){
      xArr = [];
      yArr = [];
      for (b=0; b<vLength; b++){
        xArr.push(b)
        yArr.push(myDF[a][cNames[b]]);
      }
      var pcpLine = {
        x: xArr,
        y: yArr,
        mode: 'lines',
        line: {
          color: 'orange',
          width: 1
        },
        opacity: 0.9,
      }
      Traces.push(pcpLine);
    }
    Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

    el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {
      var dLength = myDF.length
      var selectedPCP = []
      var xMin = e.range.x[0]
      var xMax = e.range.x[1]
      var yMin = e.range.y[0]
      var yMax = e.range.y[1]

      console.log([xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax])

      var Traces = []
      var drawRect = {
        type: 'rect',
        x0: xMin,
        y0: yMin,
        x1: xMax,
        y1: yMax,
        line: {
          color: 'green',
          width: 1
        },
        fillcolor: 'green'
      }
      Traces.push(drawRect);
      Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);
    })
    }", data = list(myDF = myDF, nVar = nVar, colNms = colNms))})

    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, strange as it may sound to us old `ggplot` vets, "shapes" are not handled the same way as markers and lines (which are set in "traces"), but "shapes" (like rect) are set in the `layout` part of a plotly plot. Probably I would understand this better if I read more of the plotly book..

So I made two changes.

- Changed the `dragmode` to `"select"` using `layout` at the begining.
- Changed the `Plotly.addTraces` logic at the end of your `onRender` javascript to `Plotly.relayout`

As a sidenote I have been wondering for hours why it was called "relay-out", I just now realized as I was writing this that it is "re-layout" which makes complete sense.

So here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- basicPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point(alpha=0) + xlim(0,5) +ylim(-3,3)
  gp <- ggplotly(p)

  set.seed(3)
  myDF <- data.frame(X1=rnorm(10,-1), X2=rnorm(10,-1), X3=rnorm(10,-1), X4=rnorm(10,1), X5=rnorm(10,1), X6=rnorm(10,1))
  colNms <- colnames(myDF)
  nVar <- length(colNms)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    gp %>% layout(dragmode="select") %>%  
           onRender("
                    function(el, x, data) {

                    var myDF = data.myDF
                    var Traces = [];
                    var dLength = myDF.length
                    var vLength = data.nVar
                    var cNames = data.colNms
                    for (a=0; a<dLength; a++){
                    xArr = [];
                    yArr = [];
                    for (b=0; b<vLength; b++){
                    xArr.push(b)
                    yArr.push(myDF[a][cNames[b]]);
                    }
                    var pcpLine = {
                    x: xArr,
                    y: yArr,
                    mode: 'lines',
                    line: {
                    color: 'orange',
                    width: 1
                    },
                    opacity: 0.9,
                    }
                    Traces.push(pcpLine);
                    }
                    Plotly.addTraces(el.id, Traces);

                    el.on('plotly_selected', function(e) {
                    var dLength = myDF.length
                    var selectedPCP = []
                    var xMin = e.range.x[0]
                    var xMax = e.range.x[1]
                    var yMin = e.range.y[0]
                    var yMax = e.range.y[1]

                    console.log([xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax])

                    var Traces = []
                    var drawRect = {
                    type: 'rect',
                    x0: xMin,
                    y0: yMin,
                    x1: xMax,
                    y1: yMax,
                    line: {
                    color: 'green',
                    width: 1
                    },
                    fillcolor: 'green'
                    }
                    var update = {
                        shapes:[drawRect]
                     }
                    Plotly.relayout(el.id, update)
                    })
                    }", data = list(myDF = myDF, nVar = nVar, colNms = colNms))})

  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is a screen shot of it working:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear and helpful explanation. I am sorry to ask a side question, but do you know if it might be possible to keep the selection boxes highlighted in green? Currently, they delete when the next selection is made. I tried adding persistent: 'true' to the update varaible, to Plotly.relayout(), and to layout(dragmode="select"), but those approaches did not seem to work.

Comment: Also, are you reading (https://cpsievert.github.io/plotly_book/) to understand this? I read that before, but would reread it. Thank you.

Comment: Ask it as another question, I can probably figure it out if no one beats me to it. I am working on plotly rep :)

Comment: Okay, will do! Thanks again :)

Comment: Still figuring plotly out. Ask me in a week or two and I will tell you what I have found. The book is not great.

Comment: Going to post that new question?

Comment: Yes definitely! I am still a bit stuck, and posted a new follow-up question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404638/add-permanent-shaded-rectangle-with-select-box-corners-in-plotly-r). Thank you.